# Random array-word generator

Tags: java, arrays, random

I'm trying to make a random generated array word, i dont find any problems with this code, but it just doesn't run, it doesn't show me the array's word when there is a random generated number. What is wrong with my code?

```
import java.util.Scanner;
import java.util.Random;

public class apples{
    public static void main(String[] args){
        Random dice = new Random();
        Scanner scan = new Scanner(System.in);
        String me[] = new String[5];


        me[0] = "Wow";
        me[1] = "LoL";
        me[2] = "Jis, Ji";
        me[3] = "Mes";
        me[4] = "Jus";


        System.out.println("Enter YES or NO: ");
        String roll = scan.nextLine();
        String name = "yes";
        if(roll == name){
            int result = dice.nextInt(5);
             if(result == 0){
                 System.out.println(me[0]);
             }else if(result == 1){
                 System.out.println(me[1]);
             }else if(result == 2){
                 System.out.println(me[2]);
             }else if(result == 3){
                 System.out.println(me[3]);
             }else if(result == 4){
                 System.out.println(me[4]);
             }
        }else{
            System.out.println("Bad");
        }

        }

    }
```

Comment: _just doesn't run_ Do you get prompts to enter anything? Do you get errors? Don't use `==` to compare String instances.

Comment: Check on to how to compare strings in Java.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Use string equals method to compare string instead of ==

Replace the below condition

```
if(roll == name)
```

with

```
if(roll.equals(name))
```

String equals compares the contents of the string while == checks whether the two references point to the same memory objects or not.

Read this related post to learn more about string comparsions: [Java String.equals versus ==](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/767372/java-string-equals-versus)

---

Unrelated, but instead of the chain of:

```
if (result == 0){
   System.out.println(me[0]);
```

Consider something closer to:

```
System.out.println(me[result]);
```

Comment: @Hbo-ot Can you accept the answer so that others can be benefited. You can do so by clicking on the tick mark at the left of my answer.

Comment: Didn't thought about the System.out.println(me[result]);.. thanks

Answer (score 2):

`roll==name` will always return `false` because in that case you are checking whether they refer to the same memory location.

Use `if (roll.equals(name))` instead.

Comment: While correct, the existing answer already summed it up.

Answer (score 1):

Also,

```
if(roll.equals(name)){
        int result = dice.nextInt(5);
         if(result == 0){
             System.out.println(me[0]);
         }else if(result == 1){
             System.out.println(me[1]);
         }else if(result == 2){
             System.out.println(me[2]);
         }else if(result == 3){
             System.out.println(me[3]);
         }else if(result == 4){
             System.out.println(me[4]);
         }
    }else{
        System.out.println("Bad");
    }
```

can be replaced with:

```
if(roll.equals(name))
{
     int result = dice.nextInt(5);
     System.out.println(me[result]);
}
else
{
     System.out.println("Bad");
}
```

To reduce redundant IF statements.

Comment: Umm. Although a good advice, still you didn't solve the main issue.

Comment: Yeah, just fixed it up.

Comment: @RohitJain Yeah, but it's also minutes behind the other answers--seems noisy.

Comment: Actually that was edited in just as I posted this answer.

Answer (score 0):

In java you must use equals function to compare String

```
roll.equals(name)
```

just see this for more details this [How do I compare strings in Java?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/513832/how-do-i-compare-strings-in-java)